# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO 오류: Invalid number format for port number)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, database-connection

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/myoracle"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:xe" 
            username="basic" 
            password="basic"
            maxTotal="10"
            maxIdle="5"
            maxWaitMillis="1" />
</Context>
```

this is my context.xml, and when I load the main.jsp, it shows me this error msg. oracle username and password are basic, basic. I dont understand why it's not working

```
Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO 오류: Invalid number format for port number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "xe" with your port number in the url-field. It should look like i.e. `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe`